# How to show google ads one time in android app?

Tags: android, mobile, admob, ads, adsense

I want my android app to show google ad only one time. I mean in my app it shows the ad everytime that users open the main activity. But i want it to show the ad only at the first time.

Comment: Then implement an activity that's only displayed once?

Comment: no. when the main activity opens; the ad comes out and user closes it. then user goes to another activity and comes back to main activity. At this point the ad shows up second time. but i don't want it to show more than one time.

Comment: Well, then implement a global flag that doesn't draw the ad a 2nd time.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Store a `boolean` for example, don't show the ad if it's `true` and set it to `true` after the first start.